# Creation of ledger dimension account for a vendor type account

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have to create a ledger dimension account (with a given default dimension) for a vendor type of account. Is it possible to create a ledger dimension account for vendor type of account?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward. Look at the whitepaper [Dimension White paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFIQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/3/4E36B655-568E-4D4A-B161-152B28BAAF30/Implementing_the_Account_and_Financial_Dimensions_Framework_AX2012.pdf&ei=mATRT7r3DIej4gSQmc2QDw&usg=AFQjCNGQvczoTXuUa3vg2QM-dVXmT1rqjQ&sig2=bKamDhlgXnAkLOrrdSsxWg), chapter "Setting an entity to be dimensionable".